# Maven create Spring Boot jar and plain jar with specific classes

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

Currently, my application generates 2 JAR files, one is an executable Spring Boot JAR (with an exec classifier) and the other is a normal JAR.

I want to do this so that i can share some of the classes in other projects without separating these classes out in a different project or having modules.

Currently the normal JAR contains all of the files from the project, including properties files, liquibase patches, the Main class, etc which i don't want to be shared. Is there a way to have this regular JAR contain classes from a certain package while still building the full runnable JAR with everything?

I tried using a configuration like the following with the `maven-jar-plugin`:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.2</version>
   <configuration>
      <finalName>subset</finalName>
      <includes>
         <include>org/example/stuff/**</include>
      </includes>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

and while it did seem to work for the regular JAR, it also affected the runnable JAR so that things like the resources got excluded.

Comment: Now if only you could create multiple modules with maven.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`spring-boot-maven-plugin` performs the following: it takes default project artifact and enriches it with dependencies using proprietary structure. This means if your goal is to package separate "thin" jar you need to define additional `jar` execution of `maven-jar-plugin` with specific classifier, something like:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>thin</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <classifier>thin</classifier>
                <includes>
                    <include>org/example/stuff/**</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was after. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what modules are for. Use a multi-module project.